# Error: Can't start Docker in background - getting error when installed vue storefront

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, vuejs

I am installing **Vue Storefront** using this reference [link](https://medium.com/the-vue-storefront-journal/vue-storefront-how-to-install-and-integrate-with-magento2-227767dd65b2)

when i run **npm run installer** command. i am getting below error

[image]

error log file contains below details

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'installer' ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v10.18.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preinstaller', 'installer', 'postinstaller' ]
5 info lifecycle vue-storefront@1.11.0~preinstaller: vue-storefront@1.11.0
6 info lifecycle vue-storefront@1.11.0~installer: vue-storefront@1.11.0
7 verbose lifecycle vue-storefront@1.11.0~installer: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle vue-storefront@1.11.0~installer: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/opt/lampp/htdocs/project/m2vue/vue-storefront/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle vue-storefront@1.11.0~installer: CWD: /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/m2vue/vue-storefront
10 silly lifecycle vue-storefront@1.11.0~installer: Args: [ '-c', 'node ./core/scripts/installer' ]
11 silly lifecycle vue-storefront@1.11.0~installer: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle vue-storefront@1.11.0~installer: Failed to exec installer script
13 verbose stack Error: vue-storefront@1.11.0 installer: `node ./core/scripts/installer`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid vue-storefront@1.11.0
15 verbose cwd /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/m2vue/vue-storefront
16 verbose Linux 5.0.0-37-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "installer"
18 verbose node v10.18.0
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error vue-storefront@1.11.0 installer: `node ./core/scripts/installer`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the vue-storefront@1.11.0 installer script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**Version**(installed in my system)

- npm - 6.13.4
- node - v10.18.0
- docker - Docker version 19.03.5, build
  633a0ea838
- redis-server - Redis server v=4.0.9 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-3.6.0 bits=64 build=9435c3c2879311f3

I don't know what is an issue in my followed step or version which is installed in my PC

If any one know answer then please help me. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following link it will help you:

> [Magento 2 Vue Storefront](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/303399/magento-2-vue-storefront/304323#304323)