# Magento 2 Vue Storefront error can't start docker in background

Tags: docker, magento2.3.4, npm, vue, yarn

I am implementing the vue storefront using the following reference:

> https://medium.com/the-vue-storefront-journal/vue-storefront-how-to-install-and-integrate-with-magento2-227767dd65b2
>
> https://docs.vuestorefront.io/guide/installation/linux-mac.html#using-vue-storefront-demo-as-a-backend

I have got the following error:

[image]

Can you please provide me all the steps of the docker implementing for vue I am not aware of the docker.

Implementing vue is possible without docker?

Thank you so much in Advanced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering your question `Implementing vue is possible without docker?`
In development mode of vuestorefront, you need to install docker from [here](https://medium.com/@Grigorkh/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04-3f509070d29c)
You can bypass docker in production mode as vuestorefront does not support it [currently](https://docs.vuestorefront.io/guide/installation/production-setup.html#production-setup-using-docker-kubernetes).

I have also faced the docker starting issue when I use `npm run installer` for setup for vuestorefront. so I have performed manual steps which are as below.

> Manual steps for the setup of vuestorefront on the local system

**1:** Clone vuestorefront repo to your Magento root folder.
- git clone https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront.git vue-storefront
- install dependencies using `yarn install`

**2:** Clone vuestorefrontapi
    - git clone https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront-api.git vue-storefront-api
    - install dependencies using `yarn install` or `npm i`

**3:** Copy default config to local config in vue-storefront/config/ and vue-storefront-api/config.

4: Create an integration for magento2 api call and provide details [token info] in `vue-storefront-api/config/local.json`

**5:** Go to vuestorefront-api folder and up the docker.

```
docker-compose up -d
```

**6:** Import data of magento2 to elasticsearch.
    -> `yarn mage2vs import`
    -> varify your data on `http://localhost:5601/`

**7:** Run below command form vuestorefront and vuestorefront-api
    -> `npm run dev`

**8:** Open localhost:3000 and verify your site.

> Restart all instances in manual mode.

**1:** Go to vuestorefront-api folder and up the docker.

```
docker-compose up -d
```

**2:** Import data of magento2 to elasticsearch.
    -> `yarn mage2vs import`
    -> varify your data on `http://localhost:5601/`
    Indices: `vue_storefront_catalog`

**3:** Run below command form vuestorefront and vuestorefront-api
    -> `npm run dev`

**4:** Verify your instance on localhost:3000

> Make sure you have installed all prerequisites before setup, which are
>   as below.

**1**. [Docker](https://medium.com/@Grigorkh/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04-3f509070d29c) (with docker-compose installed).
**2**. [Node.js](https://itsfoss.com/install-nodejs-ubuntu/) Active LTS (>=10.x)
**3**. [Yarn](https://www.hostinger.in/tutorials/how-to-install-yarn-on-ubuntu/) (>=1.0.0)
**4**. ImageMagick (to fit, resize and crop images)
**5**. [ElasticSearch](https://tecadmin.net/setup-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu/)
**6**. [Redis](https://tecadmin.net/install-redis-ubuntu/)

Comment: any idea about how to change URL "http://localhost:3000/" to something else like project name and also when I shut down pc then "http://localhost:3000/" this instance is not working

Comment: how to get the product image can you please describe briefly

Comment: change `host` in your `vue-storefront/config/local.json`, make sure you have something else URL pointed to your system, and added in `/etc/hosts`

Comment: Please ask different questions regarding `how to get the product image can you please describe briefly`, will try to answer there

Comment: you need to start `yarn dev` from `vue-storefront` and `vuestorefront-api` every time you close the terminal.

Comment: Please answer in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/304609/magento-2-vue-storefront-how-to-get-product-images

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104632/discussion-between-hardik-makwana-and-rizwan-khan).

Comment: I have got the error when implementing the steps. Please check the attached URL: https://prnt.sc/r6pubp

Comment: @HardikMakwana You need to stop Redis and elastic search which is already running.

Comment: can you please tell me or give me commands for stopping

Comment: `sudo service elasticsearch stop` for elasticsearch |
`sudo systemctl stop redis-server.service`, you can easily google it.

Comment: can you please how to set up the production mode? I ask a question into the https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305371/magento-2-vue-storefront-how-to-set-production-mode URL

Comment: thank u your way is very good and it worked for me. can you tell me my localhost magento 2 indexing is not working fully due to vuestorefront docker setup. how can i resolve this?

Comment: what error you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this error edit the line 197 in path

vue-storefront/core/scripts/installer.js

```
if (shell.exec(`docker-compose up -d > /dev/null 2>&1`).code !== 0) {
```

is wrong.

change condition to  "sudo docker -composer up -d"

```
if (shell.exec(`sudo docker-compose up -d`).code !== 0) {
```

By doing so, docker will successfully install in the background.

```
/**
   * Run 'docker-compose up' in background
   *
   * @returns {Promise}
   */
  dockerComposeUp () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Message.info('Starting Docker in background...')

      if (shell.exec(`sudo docker-compose up -d`).code !== 0) {
        reject(new Error('Can\'t start Docker in background.'))
      }
      // Adding 20sec timer for ES to get up and running
      // before starting restoration and migration processes
      setTimeout(() => { resolve() }, 20000)
    })
  }
```

[image]