# Magento 2 Vue Storefront How to get product images?

Tags: magento2, product-images, vue, vue-storefront

I have implemented the vue storefront successfully. But in category and product, the detail page product image is not appearing. Can you please tell me how to render the product images?

I have selected the custom URL for image endpoint:

> http://127.0.0.1/mage/pub/media/catalog/product

please check the attached screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Vuestorefront uses the ImageMagick library to resize the image so make sure you have installed that your system, You can use [this](https://tecadmin.net/install-imagemagick-on-linux/) for installation.

You need to update the `imgUrl` and `mediaUrl` in vuestorefront-`api/config/local.json` like below.

```
"magento2": {
    "imgUrl": "http://localhost/my_magento/pub/media/catalog/product",
    "mediaUrl": "http://localhost/my_magento/pub/media",
```

Update the `imageable` as per below, you need to add your hosts in it.

```
"imageable": {
    "namespace": "",
    "maxListeners": 512,
    "imageSizeLimit": 1024,
    "whitelist": {
    "allowedHosts": [
        ".*localhost",
        ".*127.0.0.1"
    ],
    "trustedHosts":[
        ".*localhost",
        ".*127.0.0.1"
    ]
}
```

Update the following in `vue-storefront/config/local.json`

```
"images": {
    "useExactUrlsNoProxy": false,
    "baseUrl": "http://localhost:8080/img/",
    "productPlaceholder": "/assets/placeholder.jpg"
}
```

After you have updated your changes in `vuestorefront-api/config/local.json` you need to again run `yarn dev` from the terminal for `vuestorefront` and `vuestorefront-api`.

Comment: I have followed steps and apply but this solution is not working for me.

Comment: what is your API URL? like `localhost:8080` http://localhost:8080/img/310/300/resize/i/m/img-11.png
Here path `i/m/img-11.png` is Magento path for image

Comment: Please check the attached screenshot

Comment: Please check the updated answer above & accept if it works for you. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

i have found a simple solution you can try that

copy all your magento 2 pub/media data in vue-storefront-api/var/magento-folder/pub/media
Or
create a symlink if you are working on localhost

vue-storefront-api/config/local.json

"magento2":
{
"imgUrl": "http://magento-domain/pub/media/catalog/product",
"assetPath": "/../var/magento-folder/pub/media",
}

vue-storefront/config/local.json

```
"images": {
     "useExactUrlsNoProxy": false,
     "baseUrl": "http://localhost:8080/img/",
     "useSpecificImagePaths": false,
     "paths": {
       "product": "/catalog/product"
     },
     "productPlaceholder": "/assets/placeholder.jpg"
   },
```

run command in vue-storefront and vue-storefront-api

```
yarn dev
```